# How to remove Space between Collection View Cell in ios in Iphone 6 and iPhone 6plus?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

i have simple `CollectionView` but it works well in `iphone 4` and `5` and 5s. but when i run in to `iphone 6` and `6plus` it look like

[image]

but i want to remove space between cell in `iphone 6` and `6 plus` . is it property for remove space ?? if is it property pls tell me.

Comment: increase dynamic width for every device using delegate method - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: about to post the same question. Thanks for saving my time and downvotes ... lol @prince

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    float width = collectionView.frame.size.width / 2;
    return CGSizeMake(width, width);

}
```

for Swift

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/2, collectionView.frame.size.width/2)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to resize the cells in order to make them fill the empty space. You need to use **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** and the **UICollectionViewFLowLayoutDelegate** and implement

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH/2)
}
```

Check out the Ray Wenderlich Tutorial for more information:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12][1]

Answer (score 1):

Increase dynamic width for every device using `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method

You Calculate width including space between two photos.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width-15)/2, (collectionView.frame.size.width-15)/2); // here 5 padding between two photos, you give hight and width here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CGFloat margin = 5.0;
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - margin)/ 2, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - margin)/ 2);
layout.minimumLineSpacing = margin;
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = margin;

UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Edit `margin` to change the space between two cells.